# Javascript: Escape " from json string

Tags: javascript, regex, json, escaping

I've got a bit of a problem. I'm currently working on converting an old system to a newer version. In the old version, data requests were managed by Java applets, which had no problems with the "-char in the data.
Now, though, I'm fetching the data from a database and converting it to a JSON-string using XSLT, and then - with the prototype-function .evalJSON() - making the string into an object.
The XSL then structure the data like this (example) :

```
{rowsets: [ { rows: [ { "ID":"xxx","OtherProperty":"yyy" } ] } ] }
```

Which in it self is OK.
Now,when there's some data in the database containing "-characters, the evalJSON() fails, because it destroys the usually well-formatted JSON string, like this:

```
{rowsets: [ { rows: [ { "ID":"xxx","OtherProperty":"yyy "more" zzz" } ] } ] }
```

Now, what i want to do, is escape the 'unwanted' "-chars somehow - without having to make some kind of Stored Procedure to du it server-side for me.
I've tried to wrap my head around a RegEx, but I'm not very experienced in that area, and therefore I'm having a really hard time figuring it out.

If it's any help, the character sequences that are sure to be legal are:
[":"] and [","]
and the sequences that are likely to appear, and should be escaped, are:
[\s"], ["\s], [",], [".] (\s indicates a whitespace)

All kinds of help is appreciated, even if it's some SQL that makes it all a lot easier :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your conversion needs to generate valid JSON!

Comment: It is very valid JSON, as long as there's no "-characters in the data set fetched from the database. Those characters is what i need to escape using some regular expression or something, before using the evalJSON() function.

Comment: "*'m fetching the data from a database and converting it to a JSON-string using XSLT*" - huh? Please post that code. This is what you need to fix to do the escaping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking a shortcut, using a string-replace template in my XSL to replace the "-characters with " before returning the JSON to my javascript function, thus not needing to escape anything client-side.

(Used this: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025173545/http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

If you're in XSLT land then you're reinventing the wheel. Google up "badgerfish" and see [here](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/xsltjson/) for a fairly solid implementation. You may of course have other problems getting in the way, but first things first.

Comment: Looking at the link you've given me, I can see that it's going to output the data just like the XSLT I'm using at the moment (ex. from site: { "alice": { "bob": [ { "$": "charlie" }, { "$": "david" } ] } }) - using "" to seperate properties and data is OK as long as there's no "-characters in the data - which in my case there is.

Comment: @freaktm: No, the xslt includes escape replacing content i.e. " -> \". Try it.